# Using the Icelandic Thorn character as a delimiter in Hive

Tags: encoding, hadoop, hive

I'm currently trying to import some DoubleClick advertising logs into Hadoop.

These logs are stored in a gzip delimited file which is encoding using page 1252 (Windows-ANSI?) and which uses the Icelandic Thorn character as a delimiter.

I can happily import these logs into a single column, but I can't seem to find a way to get Hive to understand the Thorn character - I think maybe because it doesn't understand the 1252 encoding?

I've looked at the Create Table documentation - http://hive.apache.org/docs/r0.9.0/language_manual/data-manipulation-statements.html - but can't seem to find any way to get this encoding/delimiter working.

I've also seen from https://karmasphere.com/karmasphere-analyst-faq a suggestion that the encoding for these files is ISO-8859-1 - but I don't see how to use that info in Hive or HDFS.

I know I can do a map job after import to split these rows into multiple records.

But is there an easier way to use this delimiter directly?

Thanks

Stuart

Answer (score 2):

use '\-2'
the char is a signed byte.

apparently hive devs don't think it is a problem:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-237

Comment: So something like: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_table (
  id STRING, 
  name STRING 
)
row format delimited fields terminated by '\-2'
location '/my/hdfs/location';