# Thorn character delimiter is not recognized in Hive

Tags: hadoop, encoding, hive

As mentioned in post [Using the Icelandic Thorn character as a delimiter in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833866/using-the-icelandic-thorn-character-as-a-delimiter-in-hive)
The thorn character delimiter is not recognized in Hive

Sample table

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS zzzzz_raw (
  spot_id INT,
  activity_type_id INT,
  activity_type STRING,
  activity_id INT,
  activity_sub_type STRING,
  report_name STRING,
  tag_method_id INT
)
PARTITIONED BY ( dt DATE )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY  '\-2' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/raw/data/networkmatchtablesactivity/activity_cat';`

**Output**

select * from activity_cat_raw limit 1;

```
4552126þ805759þeaasv101þ2275868þbfeaac01þBF_EA Access_Info Pageþ2       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2015-03-24
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: did you ever find a solution? I am having the same issue with the same files (doubleclick dcm logs). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer.
Instead of '-2' (thorn delimiter) , i used '-61' delimiter then a substring to remove the additional symbol, something like below

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SSSSSS (
  spot_id STRING,
  activity_type_id STRING,
  activity_type STRING,
  activity_id STRING,
  activity_sub_type STRING,
  report_name STRING,
  tag_method_id STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY ( dt STRING )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY  '\-61' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 'SSSSSS';`

and then use substring to remove other symbols

`INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE vvvvvv PARTITION (dt)
 SELECT   spot_id STRING,
  substr(activity_type_id,2),
  dt
  FROM SSSSS`

Hope it helps..